# Connection refused

Tags: networking, apt, package-management, python, proxy

When I try to install any package in Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS It show me this Error Message :

`Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused',))'

**pip :**

```
pip 9.0.1 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (python 2.7)
```

Comment: Try to remove the `rasa-nlu` using `pip` then run `sudo dpkg --configure -a`

Comment: Thank you @GAD3R,  rasa-nlu i just add as example but any package I try to install  Its show that message .

Comment: Switch  to Python3 , use `sudo update-alternatives --config python` then `sudo apt-get install --reinstall python2.7`  , switch back to Python2.7 .

Comment: Thank you @GAD3R, When i try sudo  -H pip install package name like example sudo  -H pip install rasa_nlu it work for me

Comment: sudo update-alternatives --config python : -- update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for python

Comment: see my [answer on Superuser](https://superuser.com/a/1268183/550853) to configure `update-alternative` , the must important is to solve the broken `apt`.